# eslint loader (for webpack 2) - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I'm using [eslint-loader](https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader) (for webpack 2) in my application, and I have this error:

```
./src/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/brenopolanski/github/saiku/srep-ui/saiku-report-viewer-ui/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js!/home/brenopolanski/github/saiku/srep-ui/saiku-report-viewer-ui/src/index.js Unexpected token (28:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const renderApp = (NewRoot) => {
|   render(
|     <AppContainer>
|       <NewRoot />
|     </AppContainer>,
 @ multi react-hot-loader/patch webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index
```

well... if I **remove** the `eslint-loader` in my webpack, my application work correctly, but I need the `eslint-loader` working in my webpack.

#### package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dashboard -- node server.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:webpack",
    "build:webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --config ./config/webpack.prod -p",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -c storybook",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -c storybook",
    "clean": "rimraf build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@kadira/storybook": "^2.35.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "deepmerge": "^1.3.2",
    "eslint": "^3.15.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "jest-cli": "^18.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^1.7.246",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-pdfjs": "^1.0.7",
    "react-prop-types": "^0.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

#### webpack.core.js

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlPlugin({
      title: 'Saiku Report Viewer',
      template: path.join(__dirname, '../src', 'html', 'template.html')
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        eslint: {
          configFile: path.join(__dirname, './eslint.core.js'),
          useEslintrc: false
        },
        postcss: () => {
          return [autoprefixer];
        }
      }
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss-loader',
          'stylus-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: '10000',
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: '10000',
          mimetype: 'application/svg+xml'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 8192
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ico(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  node: {
    dns: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.join(__dirname, '../src'),
      components: path.join(__dirname, '../src', 'components')
    }
  }
};
```

#### webpack.dev.js

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const core = require('./webpack.core');

module.exports = merge.smart(core, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, '../src', 'index')
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        eslint: {
          configFile: path.join(__dirname, './eslint.dev.js')
        }
      }
    })
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /(node_modules|bower_components|src)/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

#### `src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import Root from './containers/Root';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import './styl/saiku.styl';

const renderApp = (NewRoot) => {
  render(
    <AppContainer>
      <NewRoot />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.querySelector('[data-js="app"]')
  );
};

renderApp(Root);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./containers/Root', () => {
    const NewRoot = require('./containers/Root').default;
    renderApp(NewRoot);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `webpack.core.js` you define both `module.rules` and `module.loaders`. Although the `module.loaders` is still valid, for compatibility reasons, Webpack seems to ignore it when `module.rules` is present.

To solve your problem you can simply put all loaders in `module.rules`. Since you're merging the two configs, you also have to update `webpack.dev.js` to use `module.rules`, which is also recommend by the official docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules.

**webpack.core.js**

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlPlugin({
      title: 'Saiku Report Viewer',
      template: path.join(__dirname, './src', 'html', 'template.html')
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        eslint: {
          configFile: path.join(__dirname, './eslint.core.js'),
          useEslintrc: false
        },
        postcss: () => {
          return [autoprefixer];
        }
      }
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: /src/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss-loader',
          'stylus-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: '10000',
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: '10000',
          mimetype: 'application/svg+xml'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 8192
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ico(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  node: {
    dns: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
      components: path.join(__dirname, './src', 'components')
    }
  }
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const core = require('./webpack.core');

module.exports = merge.smart(core, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, './src', 'index')
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new DashboardPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        eslint: {
          configFile: path.join(__dirname, './eslint.dev.js')
        }
      }
    })
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /(node_modules|bower_components|src)/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```